# Can't find any Bluetooth devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm currently learning basics of Bluetooth technology. The code is from some tutorial I have found and it doesn't work. I've tried code from many tutorials and I can't find any Bluetooth devices. I'm wondering is something wrong with the code or is it my phone's fault (I haven't tried it on different device yet). I'm writing in Java. I'm not sure but I think something is wrong with function `onReceive` because it doesn't show a Log message.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "BT not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "asdasd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},2);
        }

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},4);
        }

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN},3);
        }
        ArrayList<String> arrayList =new ArrayList<>();


        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();




        mBroadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action=intent.getAction();

                if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    Log.i("Bluetooth DEVICES ",device.getName());
                }

                if(arrayList.size()!=0) {
                    ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
                    lv.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                }
            }
        };
        IntentFilter intentFilter =new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,intentFilter);

    }

    @Override
    protected  void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();

        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the other devices made visible? Do you get any error messages in your log?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on bluetooth and then reload your code. If that isn't it, then either your Bluetooth device or connecter isn't working properly.

Comment: what is connecter ?

Comment: Its built into the device you're using. It's what connects the Bluetooth device. If you are able to connect the Bluetooth device, it is most likely because you are using your phone, or your Bluetooth device is too primitive. If this doesn't help, you would have to do more digging or use a different device.

Comment: i'm able to connect with other devices its Samsung s8

Comment: what are you connecting? Headphones?

Comment: alright, if they are airpods, im not sure what's up, but if they are the more primitive on headphones, it won't work.

Comment: i was trying to find my mom phone

Comment: OH. Ok, i don't know anything about that. I just use the app on apple. Sorry.

Comment: no problem thank you anyway

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).